# Lucky Bamboo and yellowing leaves

Tags: leaves, bamboo

My lucky bamboo's leaves tips  started turning brown so I moved it to get more light.  This increased the problem.  Just read that direct sunlight is a no-no.  Now, the leaves are yellow to almost white. I read that the most likely situation is too much chlorine from tap water.  We have a well, so I don't think that is the problem.  I don't fertilize, but I read that they really don't need fertilizer.  I will check to see if it is root bound.  It is growing in rocks in a painted container, so I will have to remove to analyze.  However, I don't think that this is the problem either.  I will remove out of the sun, clean the water once again and check the roots.  If this does not work.......any suggestions?   Thanks

Comment: A photo of the plant would be very helpful...